# Adding Chartdroid library to an Android project

Tags: android, graph, charts

How do I add the Chartdroid library to my android project? I have gone on their website to download the source code but every way I try to add the file to my project it just shows up as gibberish and gives me an error message.

If possible could you give an extremely basic/simple explanation on how to do this because I am very new to both programming and android platforms.

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the [example app](http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/source/browse/#svn/trunk/example_apps/minimal_linechart%253Fstate%253Dclosed) working and understand how it works. Then create your own application on the level of a HelloWorld appliction which makes a simple chart from a static array of data. That should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Hi @Shane -- how did you download this example app? I have been trying to use TortoiseHg with no success...